# Lead Over Partition

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

At the moment,

i am using this function in one of the left joins::

coalesce(
(lead(AB_DATUM, 1) over (partition by OID order by AB_DATUM)) - 1,
to_date('01.01.2025', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
) as bis1_datum

But somehow, this function makes my query too slow. Could you pleas tell me what should I do to make it faster?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: What database system and version are you using because Microsoft SQL Server doesn't have a function called `to_date()`. "*Could you pleas tell me what should I do to make it faster?*" - Provide better details so that we can help you with the problem, such as the database system and version you're using, the full query you're running, the table schema with some sample data, and the execution plan.

Comment: Oracle 12g....but Tool Dynamic

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably because it’s having to sort the data to figure out what that value is. Avoid the sort by having an index, so that your data is already sorted. Without seeing the rest of the query, this might be incomplete, but try having an index on `(OID, AB_DATUM)`. Put any other columns referenced into the `INCLUDE` clause.

Comment: do you mean index(OID,AB_DATUM)

Comment: Yes. To serve the OVER clause. The partition first and then the order by. A two-key index.

Comment: somehow it is not working...can we arrange a quick call so i can show it?